# Insert 2 record to Json File

Tags: javascript, file, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm using write file to write the account after it is created

`

```
    async writeFile(path, content){
        fs.writeFile(path, content, (err) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                console.log(fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8"));
            }
        })
    }
```

`

`

```
export async function insertAccountToFile(path , emailAcc , orgName){
    let data = `{
    "LoginSuccessfully" : 
    {
        "emailAddress": "${emailAcc}",
        "password": "${globalConstants.password}",
        "org" : "${orgName}",
        "LoginStatus": "Successfully"
    }
}`
    fileHelper.writeFile(path, data)
}
```

`

I can insert to file normally, but after insert again, the new account is overwritten with the old account, so I'm not sure need to change something so that the old and the new account is still in file

Comment: Best method: use `JSON.parse()` and then set data then write file with JSON.stringify. or use use `appendFile()` method

Comment: Can you write example, not clear how to write it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `appendFile` instead of `writeFile`. Also, you need to [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) this method to use `async/await` syntaxis or use `appendFileSync`. Otherwise, there will be issues with desynchronization.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const appendFilePromisified = promisify(fs.appendFile);

async function writeFile(path, content) {
  await appendFilePromisified(path, content);
}
```